# Linking txt file info with other file

Tags: c#, arrays, file, text

I`m creating my first app,student grades book, and now i have a problem. I have a txt file full of student info(1 student for each line) and i need to link each student with their marks(they are in other file).What way do you suppose to do it? Maybe I need to make a structure of student name and 2d array?

P.S. Sorry for bad english

Here`s what i mean

Student name lastname

```
        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        // |Science   |1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10|11|12|13|14|15|
        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        // |Maths     |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
        // |English   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
```

1,2,3,4 and etc. is student grade index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        Marks = new List<StudentMark>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<StudentMark> Marks { get; set; }

    public void Load(string line)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
        Name = parts[0];
        //Other properties, if any:
        //LastName = parts[1];
    }
}
public class StudentMark
{
    public float Mark { get; set; }
    public string Lesson { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: everything is ok,but i get error at "string[] parts = line.Split(" ");" error code is "cannot convert from string to char[]"

Comment: Sorry. my bad. use `string[] parts = line.Split(' ');` instead. or `linse.Split('|');` if `|` is the delimiter. edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure as to how complex your program is, but would it be an option to create a Student object within which you would save all of the student's information including name and average grade?  This would then allow you to save other relavant information.  Otherwise, yes it would be an option to look into the dictionary class of the c# langugage.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: I have student name and i need to show all that student grades in each science,not only average grade

Comment: then I suggest you take the answer from @Mahmoodvcs as that takes into account a running list of scores.  You could change his list to use a dictionary using a datetime object or date string as a key and then a double or float for the score.  I am just wondering though, why are you using a text file instead of a database?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control of the generation of the separate student and score files?  If so can you assign a unique id to each student and store both in each file?  This would provide the link between the two.  You could add the id as a member of @mahmoodvcs' solution.  Then add logic to parse the data by id to get the relevant scores for each student.